# Range Object troubles

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project for some data analysis. I want the rows in the whole worksheet to be sorted by ascending order by their value in column "H". I am having trouble with the following:

The range objects: (see code below)

Range(or1)

Range(or2)

Something is going wrong with these range objects. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. In the Watches window I keep seeing the error "Application-defined or object defined error".

Here is the code:
'''

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("H:H")
Dim openrange1 As Range
Dim openrange2 As Range
Dim temprange As Range
Dim or1 As String
Dim or2 As String

g = 2
h = g + 1


For g = 2 To (rowcountsss - 1)
For h = g + 1 To rowcountsss
If rng.Cells(h) < rng.Cells(g) Then
or1 = "A" & g & ":" & "EN" & g
or2 = "A" & h & ":" & "EN" & h
Set openrange1 = Range(or1)
Set openrange2 = Range(or2)
Set temprange = openrange1
Set openrange1 = openrange2
Set openrange2 = temprange
Range(or1) = openrange1
Range(or2) = openrange2
End If
Next h
Next g
```

'''

Thank you so much! I look forward to learning from your answers!

Comment: the variable **rowcountsss** has not been assigned a value.

Comment: This is only a portion of my code. "rowcountsss" has a value and is an integer. If it would be helpful, I can post the full code.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: These lines: " Set openrange1 = Range(or1)
Set openrange2 = Range(or2)"

Comment: What are the specific values of `g` and `h` when the error occurs?

Comment: At the time of the error, g=2 and h=26, which means that the loop is working, because row 26 is the first instance that h<g.

Comment: Just to take a step back - what is the context for this code? "I want the rows in the whole worksheet to be sorted by ascending order by their value in column 'H'." - this can be done a lot easier right?

Comment: It is just for mass data processing. We just wanted a fast macro to crank out the same steps for the many excel files that we get back as data from MassHunter and other similar softwares. If there is a much easier way, please help me understand how!!

Comment: Does [`Range.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) not work?